# Masstransit how to test / debug a consumer which doesn't response?

Tags: c#, masstransit

In the test project I wanted to execute the codes in the `CallbackReceivedEventHandler`
So I tried to "Publish" something to this consumer but in the end the consumer is not invoked. What did I do wrong?

I had to make the consumer response something then use the RequestClient in the test project... it is not a good workaround... the consumer should not response anything

please help

## Application Project

```
public class CallbackReceivedEventHandler : IConsumer<CallbackReceivedEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CallbackReceivedEvent> context) 
    {
        //Breakpoint is here
        ...
        await context.RespondAsync(new CallbackReceivedEventResponse()); // I want to remove this thing
    }
```

## Test Project

```
provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        configurator.AddConsumers(typeof(CallbackReceivedEventHandler));
    })
    .AddGenericRequestClient()
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);

var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
await harness.Start();

var bus = provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();

CallbackReceivedEvent input = new()

// NOT WORK
await bus.Publish(input); //KO! the consumer is not called (breakpoint in Consume is not hit)

// WORK!
var requester = bus.CreateRequestClient<CallbackReceivedEvent>();
await requester.GetResponse<CallbackReceivedEventResponse>(input); //OK! the consumer is called (breakpoint in Consume is hit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your test is completing before the message has been dispatched to the consumer. Messages are delivered asynchronously.

In your test, after the publish, you can await the InactivityTask on the test harness to ensure the message was dispatched. Or you could wait for the message to be consumed. Either approach works, but one is more specific ensuring that the message was published.

```cs
await bus.Publish(input);

await harness.Consumed.Any<CallbackReceivedEvent>();
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or not, but in 8.0.15 awaiting the InactivityTask is the only way I am able to see that message was consumed.

await harness.Consumed.Any<CallbackReceivedEvent>(); is always false, wheras

await harness.InactivityTask;
await harness.Consumed.Any<CallbackReceivedEvent>(); is true

Comment: On MassTransit 8.1.1-develop I'm still seeing what Nick describes here ... if I don't await harness.InactivityTask then I get to the next lines of the test before the handler has completed, and hence with unexpected previous values.  If you are not using a request client then await InactivityTask before testing the changes applied by your handlers until this is fixed.

Comment: Well, this example is using the obsolete `AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness`, so it really is no longer applicable.